# jBreadcrumbs not applying correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, breadcrumbs

Hello I am trying to apply jBreadCrumb1.1.js (http://www.comparenetworks.com/developers/jqueryplugins/jbreadcrumb.html) to a webpage.

I am not sure what the problem is as part of the functionality applies but the collapsible features do not.

I have downloaded a working demo and i am slowly pulling from it trying to find my problem.

I think it may be that within another plugin there is the same identifier or potentially a css file I am not sure.

```
<!-- Styles -->

<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./styles/images/favicon.ico"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/jquery.mobile.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/jqm-docs.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/Base.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/BreadCrumb.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/mystyles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/jquery.jqplot.css" />

<!-- Scripts -->

<script src="./scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="./scripts/myscripts.js"></script>
<script src="./scripts/serverCommunication.js"></script>
<script src="./scripts/myplotting.js"></script>
<script src="./scripts/jquery.jqplot.js"></script>
<script src="./scripts/jqplot.cursor.min.js"></script>
<script src="./scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>

<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="./scripts/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->

<script src="./scripts/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
<script src="./scripts/jqm-docs.js"></script>
<script src="./scripts/jquery.jBreadCrumb.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="./scripts/stupidtable.js"></script>
```

Here is a list of all imported plugins/scripts and jQuery is up to date.

At the moment some css formatting applies but the collapsible features do not.

Perhaps someone has come across this before I will find the issue eventually but I feel like it may be starring me in the face and I am just not seeing it.

*Not my code originally so trying to add requested functionality another reason I feel it may be staring me in the face without my knowing.

Any help is appreciated cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out jBreadCrumbs was using a different version of jQuery in the demo I had and I have discovered it is incompatible with certain other features in the webpage which has lead me to use a new plugin most like xbreadcrumbs.